# How to add a library in python

Tags: python

I am trying to authenticate `jawbone` api in python. In the code there is a line:

```
import requests
```

How can I add this. I have very little knowledge on python. Just manipulating the code. Can any one please help? The library is already present in python 3.3

Comment: What is the error? What is the expected behavior? What do you get?

Comment: @soulseekah It is showing module requests not found

Comment: run `pip install requests` then

Comment: where should i run this command.I tried this command in console but its showing syntax error.. @soulseekah

Comment: http://requests.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user/install/#install

Comment: @soulseekah's comment is probably the answer you're looking for. Additionally, I'd recommend the [requests_oauthlib](http://requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library as it's built on top of requests and handles the OAuth connection for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is only for the users using python33 and in windows platform,,,, 
download Requests packages from any site.
Copy the folder Requests from the downloaded package and place it on C://python33/LIB/ folder.... 
now you are able to import Requests package to your program**